# Auto calling js function from child iframe after reload is not working

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child

I have a php based webpage and inside it `iframe` with another webpage. Parent contains list of items, and iframe contains page that will add/edit the list, save it to DB and send a js message to parent page (list) to `update list without reloading parent page` (a litle bit more complicated then that, but that is the core idea).

```
//html parent page basic content
<head>
    <script>
        function alert_me(){
            alert('IT\'S ALIVE!');
        }
    <script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src='child_page.html'></iframe>
</body>
```

And now the child page.

```
<head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            //this is not working and this is what I want (auto call function after reload child)
            window.top.alert_me();

            //I tried autoclick button but it's not working either
            $('.alert_me_button').trigger('click');

        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- this is working just fine, so I know the code itself is ok -->
    <a href="#" class="alert_me_button" onclick="window.top.alert_me();" >Click me to alert me</a>
</body>
```

As you see It works fine when user click the button callij js funtion, but it will not work the I don't want any user action. I triend , documnt.ready()... even  setInterval() to pause the script to be sure it's not timing issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works just fine.
What browser are you using. I just copied your code and added jquery from cdn. I used SimpleHttpServer to serve the pages and avoid the cross origin blocking.

After reloading I got the message twice both in Chrome and Firefox as well.

Comment: I'm using firefox too (65.0 64 bit)... this strange. I also checked on chrome and I have same problem - let me restart pc just to be sure.

Comment: Are you using a local http server? Are you working remotly? Are there any messages in the console output in chrome?

Comment: I'm using xamp and run page from localhost. `avoid the cross origin blocking` - maybe its good direction to consider what is the problem? I triend both full link http:/localhost/...parent.php and just parent.php - same result - not working

Comment: `Are there any messages in the console output in chrome?` - nothing on firefox console, I will try chrome too. I work on local serwer

Comment: cross origin blocking seems not to be a problem as it works when clicking on the link

Comment: Thant you for your time. Problem was this <script type="javascript"> != <script type="text/javascript">. And the thing is there was no error or anything, yet it was broking the working of js (but it seems not all of it - I will investigate this a litle bit more when I find time). Simple <script> works too just fine too.